# algorithm: analyzing web pages for tags

Tags: c#, algorithm, search-engine, information-retrieval, information-extraction

I've been working on a project in the last few days and there is a task in this project that I actually don't know how to do, the project includes analyzing web pages to find tags that Characterizes the page.

**hey buddy , what you mean by tags?** by saying tags I mean keywords that summarize what the web page about.  For example here on SO you write you're own tags so people can find you're question better.  What I am talking about is building an algorithm to analyze the web pages to find it's tags by the text within the page.

I started with getting the text from the page -> **accomplished**

generally im looking for a way to find the keywords that Concludes what the webpage about

However, I don't really know what to do next. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: What you describe is that you have some text (be it from web page or anywhere) and want to characterize it by picking some words and declare them to be tags ?

Comment: Are you targeting specific types of webpage? eg ones that implement the stackoverflow api? Or are you targeting generic web pages. If it's the latter then I think you're going to have difficulties. Different sites will implement 'tags' in their own ways. If it's the former then it should be quite straightforward...

Comment: generally im looking for a way to find the keywords that Concludes what the webpage about

Answer (score 4):

For a really basic approach, you could use the [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) algorithm to find the most important word in your page

> **Quick overlook from wikipedia:**
>
> The tf–idf weight (term frequency–inverse document frequency) is a
>   weight often used in information retrieval and text mining. This
>   weight is a statistical measure used to evaluate how important a word
>   is to a document in a collection or corpus. The importance increases
>   proportionally to the number of times a word appears in the document
>   but is offset by the frequency of the word in the corpus. Variations
>   of the tf–idf weighting scheme are often used by search engines as a
>   central tool in scoring and ranking a document's relevance given a
>   user query. tf–idf can be successfully used for stop-words filtering
>   in various subject fields including text summarization and
>   classification

Once you find the most important word in your page you can use them as tags.

---

If you want to improve your tags and make them more relevant.

There are a lot of way to proceed, but you can proceed as below:

- Extract a bunch of text from which you know the main tags.
- For all this text run a TF-IDF algorithm and create a vector with the
  ones with the highest score.
- Try to find a main direction will all these vectors. (running an ACP
  for example, or any machine learning tool)
- And use this tag to represent the set of words from the main direction. (the largest vector of the ACP)

Hope it's understandable and it helps

Answer (score 1):

Typically you look for certain words surrounded by certain html.  For example, titles are typically in an H tag such as `<h1>`.

If you parse a page for all of it's H1 tags then it stands to reason that the content following that tag is related.  An example is this very page.  It has an H1 tag surrounding the question title.  This gives google a hint that the page is about "algorithm", "analyzing", "web pages", etc.

The hard part is to determine context.

In our example here, the term "pages" is very generic and can relate to anything.  However "web pages" are a bit more specific.  You can do this with an internal dictionary that is built up over time based on term frequency after analyizing a number of documents to find commonality.  The frequency should provide a weighted value in determining the top X "tags" for a given page.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an [Information Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval) and Data Mining question. Reviewing some of [Rao's lectures](http://rakaposhi.eas.asu.edu/cse494/) may help.

When you're spidering web pages, you're essentially trying to build an index.  You do this by building a global Term-Frequency dictionary, where each word in the language (often [stemmed](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/) to account for pluralization and other modifications) is stored as a key, and the number of times they occur in the document as values.

From there, you can use algorthms such as [PageRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) and [Authorities and hubs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HITS_algorithm) to do data analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a number of heuristics:

- Acronyms and words in all uppercase
- Words that are not frequent, i.e. discard words that appear in all or most documents and favour the ones that appear relatively frequently only on this one.
- Sequences of words that always appear in the same order in this document and possibly in others as well
- etc.